# wi-fi hardware disabled in ubuntu 18.04 how to fix this?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, wifi-hardware-switch

i am using acer 4755 laptop with core i3 2310m proc. it can't turn on wi-fi. on windows OS acer laptop usually use fn + F3 to switch the wi-fi on.but it doesn't work. how to install the driver properly and how to turn it on??

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: We need to know what wifi card is in the machine in order to tell you how to install the correct driver.  You can go to a terminal and enter this command and post the output here if your unsure of the card model.  **sudo lshw -C network**

Comment: lspci -kkn | grep -A3
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.

Comment: rfkill list ;
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN ;
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN ;
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN ;
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes